# Is consciousness universal?

Tags: consciousness, existence, reality, universals, panpsychism

I have just read "Why" by Philip Goff. He proposes that matter consists of conscious entities. Physics based on mathematics tells us what matter does, not what it is. This has implications for the origin of the universe and its development. It also impacts on our understanding of human consciousness. There is the potential for the development of universal values, the first of which is existence itself. But is this a coherent model of reality?

(To clarify, in my view, consciousness at the fundamental level is awareness, for example quantum entanglement yields paired particles with mutual awareness. Humans are self-conscious, as are parrots, for example, since they pass the mirror test. Other life forms are sentient.)

The intent of the question is to explore how this idea hangs together - or not.

Comment: You can reasonably postulate it because it does not seem to be derivable from current properties of matter.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain what this means. Are you asking if a quark could write a symphony? Do protons contemplate the infinite? Does a lemon have self-awareness? These are three very different questions but all would fall under matter consisting of conscious entities.

Comment: I cannot help. Our actual discussion about Goff’s universal consciousness, invoking panpsychism and the trinity, reminds me of  feeding birds: After someone disseminates some breadcrumbs, birds are rushing over immediately to peck the pieces. - Why not waiting to hear Goff’s arguments and to see which philosophical problem can be solved by this hypothesis? -  
Because I also pecked Goff’s breadcrumbs, I do not exempt myself from the bird analogy :-)

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCPCyri1rXU&t=5290s) is a decent debate between Goff and Carroll.

Answer (score 2):

Universality of consciousness is a typical position of *panpsychism*. According to the [IEP encyclopedia](https://iep.utm.edu/panpsych/#H3)

> Panpsychism is the view that all things have a mind or a mind-like
> quality.

1. Mind as we know it from humans presupposes the capability of
   information processing, in particular constructing high-level
   perceptions from sense stimuli. Moreover, mind is the capability to
   assess the input information and to make corresponding decisions.
   The minimal presupposition for the human mind is the nervous system of the organism.
2. Currently neuroscience investigates the neural correlate of
   consciousness (NCC), see e.g., Christof Koch ‘s book
   [Consciousness](https://www.amazon.de/Consciousness-MIT-Press-Christof-Koch/dp/0262017490).

   Apparently the nervous system including the human brain is a highly
   complex system, possibly the most complex system we know. It took
   evolution millions of years to develop this system of information
   processing and decision making.
3. If Goff  “proposes that matter consists of conscious entities” I
   would like to learn about some of his arguments. I do not know a
   convincing argument to support his claim. But there are some obvious
   arguments against his claim, e.g., non-animate objects do not show a behaviour which could be interpreted as the result of conscious information processing.

   I would also like to learn which
   scientific problems can be solved by making the hypothesis of
   panpsychism.
4. Hence - because you read Goff’s book - could you please indicate
   some arguments from his book which you find convincing. This could give your question some more context.

Answer (score 2):

> Is consciousness universal?

Given the rest of your question, universal here presumably means that every bit of matter is conscious. This is committing the same fallacies as the Trinity. Allow me to explain. The idea of the Trinity (in the Christian doctrine) is that the Trinity is one person, God, made of three persons,  God the Father, God the Son (Jesus Christ) and God the Holy Spirit. The problem starts when we remember that a person is something which is supposed (in the Christian doctrine) to possess free will. Ah. How does it works? The Trinity has free will and wants to go visit the Eiffel Tower. However, God the Father also has free will and wants to visit the Taj Mahal. Jesus Christ also has free will and want to visit Jerusalem once more, while God the Holy Spirit just wants to stay put. With the idea that every bit of matter possess consciousness, we end up with a similarly overegged pudding where there would be an infinite number of consciousness layers for every bit of matter, a sort of Meinongian inflation.

> I have just read "Why" by Philip Goff. He proposes that matter consists of conscious entities. Physics based on mathematics tells us what matter does, not what it is.

The crucial point about the brain is that it is a cognitive system. And, this is the only system we actually know that it is conscious. A sandwich presumably is not a cognitive system, and if it possessed consciousness, it would be so thin as to be virtually inexistent. I would say that it is not even measurable, if by that we mean that it could not even answer the question of whether it is conscious.

> This has implications for the origin of the universe and its development.

Only if we first established what physical relation there would be between matter and consciousness, which is precisely what we seem unable to do.

> It also impacts on our understanding of human consciousness.

I doubt that very much. The subject has been discussed to death for the last 3,000 years and we are barely wiser than Plato. The current literature is systematically confusing, as you do yourself, between the informational contents of our mind and our subjective experience of them. The former can clearly be reproduced by machine, the latter is as elusive today as it ever was. Confusing these two very different aspects can only lead to the wrong conclusion.

> There is the potential for the development of universal values,

This would concern the informational contents of our mind. And I was under the impression that humanity didn't wait for Philip Goff to try and develop universal values. The irony here is that it is precisely the self-interest of each conscious blob of matter who is a legitimate member of humanity which denies the application of those universal values to anyone but themselves.

> the first of which is existence itself.

Existence a *universal value*?! Kant for one would have strongly objected. You *really* need to exist before you could even think about developing universal values.

Comment: Plus one for some robust common sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is one proposed answer to the signature conundrum of modern Western philosophy, the "**mind/body problem.**" The mental and the physical appear to be quite different, but they also appear to be closely intertwined? Why, and how?

- One classic approach is called ***dualism***. Associated most closely with Descartes (but arguably implied in the Judeo-Christian religious tradition), it accepts mind and body as two separate, fundamental building blocks of the universe. This, however, is unsatisfying to many people--it more *describes* our intuitions than *explains* why the universe would be composed that way.
- The most dominant current viewpoint is called *physical monism*, or ***physicalism***. It holds that fundamentally, everything is matter, and that things like consciousness are just patterns of matter. The unsolved conundrum of physicalism is to explain *how* something like consciousness can arise from a purely physical universe.
- A competing viewpoint (currently deeply unpopular, but perhaps on the verge of a revival) is *ideal monism* or ***idealism*** which holds that fundamentally, the universe is mental, and that physical objects are built inside of a mental space. The unsolved conundrum for idealism is to explain *why* there would be the appearance of a physical universe at all. It's not hard to hypothesize that the universe could be a hallucination in the mind of God. But why? And what would be the point and the origin of the specific physical rules that seem to govern our existence?

Goff's approach (which is not unique to him) is to hypothesize that the fundamental building blocks of the universe are neither purely material, nor purely mental, but have **aspects of both**. Just like the electron is said to have a "dual" nature--it is neither a wave, nor a particle, but can behave as either, situationally--so too, in the panpsychic universe, it would be said to also have a mental aspect, one that we wouldn't see evidence of until a great many such particles were assembled in certain complex patterns, such as a brain, or (arguably) an artificially intelligent supercomputer.

The appeal of this is that it superficially appears to address both the *how* question of physicalism, and the *why* question of idealism. But at this point, it's purely speculative, and divorced from real-world concerns. Unless, and until, proponents can demonstrate that it has superior **explanatory AND predictive value for real-world problems**, it is unlikely to gain widespread acceptance (it would need to be able to outcompete other hypotheses).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean. If you mean consciousness of the sort experienced by humans, then there are all kinds of reasons to object to the idea. To pick one at random, that sort of consciousness seems to be a process that requires energy to sustain it, and there is no evidence of corresponding energy consumption by inanimate matter such as rocks, etc.  If you mean some form of primitive building block of consciousness, that might be vacuously true, since consciousness seems to be dependent on electrical activity, and the basic components of that, namely electrical charges and fields, do seem to be everywhere. If by consciousness you mean some form of experience, then again it can be vacuously true that electrons, say, experience forces, but that is simply a play on words. Goff isn't even close to a definition of what he means by universal consciousness that is capable of being unambiguously understood, let alone tested.